# Ubuntu hangs while restoring deja-dup backup

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, and yesterday, I made a complete backup of my system using Deja-Dup, backing up everything on /.

When I attempted to restore the backup, Ubuntu froze while Deja-Dup was restoring the file `/lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_352.ko`.

[image]

Then I made a new backup, excluding `/lib/modules` directory, and tried to restore this new backup. Same thing happened, but while restoring a different file, this time it was `/lib/firmware/ti-connectivity/wl128x-fw-5-sr.bin`.

[image]

Need your help with identifying what causes this behavior, and how to avoid it. Also, I want to know which directories (beside `/home`) should be backed up, and whether `/lib` is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to restore system files to their original location meaning that they may overwrite files that are *currently in use by the kernel*. Don't do that! Either

- restore your files to a different location than the root directory (`/`),
- restore them from a different system (e. g. a live DVD/USB) onto the root file system of the target drive, or
- restore only the files from the back-up that you need.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: Sorry for digging up this old question. How can I only restore the files from the backup that I need? My restore is stuck at a very large file which I don't need anymore (not a system file!). How can I remove or exclude it from the backup before restoring it?

Comment: @Fred: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.